# Particular current divider

Tags: circuit-analysis, voltage-divider, kirchhoffs-laws

Consider this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxOpXS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(this part is preceeded and followed by other components).

$$I_1 + I_2 = \displaystyle \frac{V_1}{sL_{12}} - \frac{V_3}{sL_{12}} \left( \displaystyle \frac{L_1}{L_1 + L_2} \right)$$

with

$$L_{12} = L_1 || L_2 = \displaystyle \frac{L_1 L_2}{L_1 + L_2}$$

How can this relation be obtained? Any hint?

The ratio \$ \displaystyle \frac{L_1}{L_1 + L_2} \$ seems a voltage divider; but I can't see anything similar. Moreover, \$ L_1 \$ and \$ L_2 \$ are not parallel.

Comment: Just realize that \$\frac 1 {s L_{12}} (\frac {L_1} {L_1+L_2})=\frac 1 {sL_2}\$

Comment: Thank you! It is a substitution. If you give it as an answer, I will chose it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just realize that \$\frac 1 {sL_{12}} (\frac {L_1} {L_1+L_2})=\frac 1 {sL_2}\$

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it would be more direct to see that 
$$I_1 + I_2 = \displaystyle \frac{V_1}{sL_{1}} + \frac{V_1 - V_3}{sL_{2}}$$
and that $$L_{1} = \displaystyle L_{12} \left(\displaystyle \frac{L_1+L_2}{L_2} \right) $$ From there it's just algebra to see that it's equivalent to what you've got.